# Enable Windows Azure Diagnostics extension (WAD) with XML file to multiple vms at the same time

Tags: xml, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to enable Azure Diagnostics extension (WAD) with Powershell / Azurebook using XML file. I'm able to get this working only on single vm at time because XML file has this line in there (without it don't work, atleast i think so [link to it](http://%3CMetrics%20resourceId=%22/subscriptions/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyWindowsVM%22%20%3E)) where i specify vm's name and resource group.

`<Metrics resourceId="/subscriptions/11111111-1111-1111-1111111111111111/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyWindowsVM" >`

My XML file which is stored in Azure storage account.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
    <WadCfg>
      <DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration overallQuotaInMB="4096">
        <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error"/>
        <PerformanceCounters scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="CPU utilization" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Privileged Time" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="CPU privileged time" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% User Time" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="CPU user time" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Processor Information(_Total)\Processor Frequency" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="CPU frequency" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\System\Processes" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Processes" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Process(_Total)\Thread Count" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Threads" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Process(_Total)\Handle Count" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Handles" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="Memory usage" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available Bytes" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Bytes">
        <annotation displayName="Memory available" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Committed Bytes" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Bytes">
        <annotation displayName="Memory committed" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Commit Limit" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Bytes">
        <annotation displayName="Memory commit limit" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Bytes">
        <annotation displayName="Memory paged pool" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Bytes">
        <annotation displayName="Memory non-paged pool" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Time" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="Disk active time" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Read Time" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="Disk active read time" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\% Disk Write Time" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="Disk active write time" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Transfers/sec" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="CountPerSecond">
        <annotation displayName="Disk operations" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Reads/sec" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="CountPerSecond">
        <annotation displayName="Disk read operations" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Writes/sec" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="CountPerSecond">
        <annotation displayName="Disk write operations" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Bytes/sec" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="BytesPerSecond">
        <annotation displayName="Disk speed" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Read Bytes/sec" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="BytesPerSecond">
        <annotation displayName="Disk read speed" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Disk Write Bytes/sec" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="BytesPerSecond">
        <annotation displayName="Disk write speed" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Queue Length" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Disk average queue length" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Disk average read queue length" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\PhysicalDisk(_Total)\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Disk average write queue length" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Percent">
        <annotation displayName="Disk free space (percentage)" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration counterSpecifier="\LogicalDisk(_Total)\Free Megabytes" sampleRate="PT60S" unit="Count">
        <annotation displayName="Disk free space (MB)" locale="en-us"/>
      </PerformanceCounterConfiguration>
    </PerformanceCounters>
    **<Metrics resourceId="/subscriptions/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyWindowsVM" >**
        <MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1H"/>
        <MetricAggregation scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M"/>
    </Metrics>
    <WindowsEventLog scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <DataSource name="Application!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"/>
      <DataSource name="Security!*[System[(Level=0 or Level=1)]]"/>
      <DataSource name="System!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"/>
    </WindowsEventLog>
      </DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
            <SinksConfig>
<Sink name="AzureMonitorSink">
            <AzureMonitor> 
           </AzureMonitor>
        </Sink>
 </SinksConfig>
    </WadCfg>
    <StorageAccount>storage account name</StorageAccount>
</PublicConfig>
```

Then I found this [diagnostics-configuration-variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/diagnostics-template?toc=/azure/azure-monitor/toc.json#diagnostics-configuration-variables) where it stated I could somehow maybe be possible to insert more vm names or somehow dodge that line so I could mass install that without needed to change xml after every install but things it that my xml and another scripting skills kinda ended already...

Do you have ideas how could this be done so I could use that xml (or maybe json?) file to install that extension to many vm's at the same time using Powershell / Runbooks?

Script that I use to deploy extension which work with one vm at the time.

```
$SAResourceGroupName="rg name"
$StorageAccountName="storage account name"

$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
$Context=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$tmpStart = Get-Date
$tmpEnd = $tmpStart.AddHours(2.0)
$SASToken = New-AzStorageBlobSASToken -Blob "DiagnosticsPubConfig.xml" -Container "scripts" -Context $Context -Permission r -StartTime $tmpStart -ExpiryTime $tmpEnd -FullURI



Set-AzVMDiagnosticsExtension -ResourceGroupName COMMVM-SUB2012-RG -VMName nalle9002 -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "$SASToken" -StorageAccountName storage account name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it somehow working with using this in xml.

```
<Metrics resourceId="/subscriptions/subscription().subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroup().name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vmName">
```

When using Powershell I get error but it still works (at least for now).

*WARNING: The resourceId defined in the config file does not match the actual resource's id.*